# Grails - Error in build config

Tags: grails, ggts

I tried to run the generate-all myPackage.* from GGTS.
It showed me a lot of errors. So i checked the problem with "test-app -unit ats.JD"

And this is the issue i get.

`There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates mysql:mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

Comment: Which grails version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added a wrong path to the mysql connector lib. Please, recheck it in your BuildConfig.groovy file

Comment: @Judithkaushik if it helped you, please mark my answer as right